# Write data from two files to one file

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I have two files: `file1`(4 columns) and `file2` (4 columns). I want to write all of these data into one file (4 columns from `file1` the 4 columns from `file2` = total 8 columns).

I have started writing the code but not able to finish. Please help me.

```
program dataarranhe
  implicit none
  character*80 :: File1, File2
  integer :: i
  open(1,file='File1')
  open(2,file='File2')
  open(3,file='outfile',status='unknown')

  i = 0
  do
     i = i + 1
     read(1,'(80a)')File1


end program dataarrange
```

File1:

```
    -9.568336E+00  -1.615161E+00   1.042644E+00  -1.615161E+00
    -4.765572E-01   9.005122E-01  -2.282920E+00   9.005122E-01
    -1.012710E+01   4.672368E-01   8.791873E-02   4.672368E-01
    -7.699012E+00  -9.906154E-01   7.450304E-01  -9.906154E-01
    -3.544260E+00   4.254020E+00  -1.963602E+00   4.254020E+00
```

File2

```
    -1.131916E+01  -6.979813E-01  1.042644E+00 -6.979813E-01
    -3.827857E+00  -3.206736E+00 -2.282920E+00 -3.206736E+00
    -4.680832E+00  -5.271814E-01  8.791873E-02 -5.271814E-01
    -1.061230E+00  -3.546956E+00  7.450304E-01 -3.546956E+00
     3.740858E+00  -4.587760E+00 -1.963602E+00 -4.587760E+00
```

I want the following results

```
    -9.568336E+00  -1.615161E+00   1.042644E+00  -1.615161E+00 -1.131916E+01  -6.979813E-01  1.042644E+00 -6.979813E-01
    -4.765572E-01   9.005122E-01  -2.282920E+00   9.005122E-01 -3.827857E+00  -3.206736E+00 -2.282920E+00 -3.206736E+00
    -1.012710E+01   4.672368E-01   8.791873E-02   4.672368E-01 -4.680832E+00  -5.271814E-01  8.791873E-02 -5.271814E-01
    -7.699012E+00  -9.906154E-01   7.450304E-01  -9.906154E-01 -1.061230E+00  -3.546956E+00  7.450304E-01 -3.546956E+00
    -3.544260E+00   4.254020E+00  -1.963602E+00   4.254020E+00  3.740858E+00  -4.587760E+00 -1.963602E+00 -4.587760E+00
```

Comment: `read(1,'(a)')File1;read(2,'(a)')File2;write(3,'(3a)')trim(File1),' ',trim(file2)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are an a Unix-type system and have access to `paste` you can simply do

```
$ paste File1 File2
```

For this sort of problem, scripting is your friend; you'll save yourself a huge amount of time using `bash`, `sh` or something similar rather that Fortran here. However, I appreciate that this decision may not be in your hands. If so, comment, and I can expand the answer to include a Fortran solution.